# < operator in UNIX, passing to Perl script

Tags: perl, command-line, stdin

When evaluating `if(-t STDIN)`, does the < UNIX operator count as STDIN? If not, how do I get that data?

So someone types `perl example.pl < testing.txt`. This doesn't behave like data piped in via `ls | ./example.pl`. How can I get that behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Test `-p STDIN`, which checks if the filehandle `STDIN` is attached to a pipe.

```
touch foo
perl -e 'print -p STDIN' < foo            # nothing
cat foo | perl -e 'print -p STDIN'        # 1
```

But I'm not sure I understand your question. In all three of these cases

```
1.  perl -e 'print $_=<STDIN>' < <(echo foo)
2.  echo foo | perl -e 'print $_=<STDIN>'
3.  perl -e 'print $_=<STDIN>'          # then type "foo\n" to the console
```

the inputs are the same and all accessible through the `STDIN` filehandle. In the first two cases, `-t STDIN` will evaluate to false, and in the second case, `-p STDIN` will be true.

The differences in behavior between these three cases are subtle, and usually not important. The third case, obviously, will wait until at least one line of input (terminated with "\n" or EOF) is received. The difference between the first two cases is even more subtle. When the input to your program is piped from the output of another process, you are somewhat at the mercy of that first process with respect to latency or whether that program buffers its output.

Maybe you could expand on what you mean when you say

```
perl example.pl < testing.txt
```

doesn't behave like

```
ls | ./example.pl
```

Comment: `If not, how do I get that data?`

Answer (score 2):

`-t` tests whether or not `STDIN` is attached to a tty.

When you pipe data to perl, it will not be attached to a tty.  This should not depend on the mechanism you use to pipe (ie, whether you pipe a command using `|` or pipe a file using `<`.)  However, you will have a tty attached when you run the program directly.  Given the following example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print ((-t STDIN) ? "is a tty\n" : "is not a tty\n");
```

You would expect the following output:

```
% perl ./ttytest.pl
is a tty
% perl ./ttytest.pl < somefile
is not a tty
% ls | perl ./ttytest.pl
is not a tty
```